# What should be done to the question which contain wrong spoiler?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, spoilers, question-quality

A few months ago I read [this *Twilight* question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26738/what-were-the-reasons-for-the-completely-different-ending-in-the-twilight-saga), which contains the wrong spoiler for the ending of *Breaking Dawn Part 2*. At that time I hadn't watched the film, but I read the spoiler, and I believed that it was true. But after finally watching it today, I got to know that it contains the completely wrong ending spoiler.

So what should be done with this kind of question, where wrong information is given?

Comment: Well, @Saffron seems to be correcting it in the answer.  Is the correction correct?  (I'm not a Twilight fan)

Comment: The correction is  absolutely correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A question that has no basis in reality (either real world, or in-universe) seems of little use to anyone.  I voted to close the question as not constructive, but too localized would also be an acceptable close reason for this sort of situation.

This particular question could maybe be edited to match the actual contents of the film, if there are some significant differences between the book and film.

Answer (score 5):

You should down vote the question. In this particular case, it looks like a straight up troll question. It appears that the question was asked just so the wrong info would be seen by people. Especially because the movie didn't even hit theaters until the 16th of Nov. and this question was asked Nov 12.

Comment: ... and the user has only asked the one question, and hasn't returned since, not even to view the answer.